# Cygwin - export vs. SET

Tags: cygwin, cygpath

I have written a little bash script to switch the JAVA Version in Cygwin: http://pjsdev.blogspot.de/2013/02/cygwin-switching-java-version.html

As you can see I am using "export" to set the ENV & PATH. This works fine in command line tools running under Cygwin shell. But how can I force to set the Variables in Win7 advanced system settings? In a batch script SET would be the command to use, but are there any posibilities in Cygwin to call SET or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Call the Windows API From a Cygwin Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981499/how-do-i-call-the-win32-api-from-a-cygwin-program), as you will have to call out to Windows to change the Environment for Windows programs.